# React Native App Crash in Android 11 If Given One Time Permission To Access Camera

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, android-permissions, android-11

I have an app in react native for Android, when a user opens the camera it asks for Permission. In Android 11 user has two options in permission "**ONLY THIS TIME**" and "**WHILE USING THE APP**", to give access of the camera.

If the user selects the "**ONLY THIS TIME**" option, it opens the camera. Then, if the user takes 45 sec to 1 min to click picture, App gets crashes. The same is working fine in case the user selects the "**WHILE USING THE APP**" option to grant permission.

I think this is happing because, in **One Time Permission**, Android revokes permission after a few seconds. Let me know if anyone has a better explanation and solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix it?